# How to open a page in incognito mode from HTML?

Tags: private-browsing

As a sysadmin, I frequently want to open internal web apps in incognito mode, for a variety of reasons that have nothing to do with privacy.  To use a different set of credentials, perhaps.  Or to prevent cross-contamination between two sessions with the same app. Or ... well, you get it, we're all running complex systems.

I would love to be able to make a link open in an incognito tab or window (ideally in all browsers, but primarily in Opera).  Something like:

```
<a target="_incognito" href="https://were.hunting.wabbits.com">Qwiet</a>
```

Or:

```
<a href="javascript:OpenInIncognito('https://were.hunting.wabbits.com');">Qwiet</a>
```

Or, worst case, make a bookmark do that.

Every discussion I can find of this boils down to "*You shouldn't want to do that because ... privacy!*".  But, of course, this isn't a privacy use case, and I really couldn't care less if a forensic investigator can find out I've been accessing these web apps.  It's part of my job, after all.  I just want some isolation, and I'd like to do it without opening a variety of different browsers or using multiple machines or VMs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a desktop shortcut and use the -incognito flag and the web address to get it done, as per the following page:

https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/incognito-mode-shortcut/

This is a bit worse than the "worst case" you outlined, but if you'll be testing the same pages repeatedly, it might not be so bad.

Comment: Yeah, that's worse-than-worst :-)  But it's a viable option, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You may achieve that with the JavaScript function `windows.create()`, it accepts an optional `incognito` parameter, see [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/create#Parameters):

> **incognito**
>   Whether the new window should be an incognito (private) window. Note that if you specify incognito and tabId, the ID must refer to a private tab — that is, you can't move a non-private tab to a private window.

Example:
`windows.create({"url": url, "incognito": true});`

Check [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/create#Browser_compatibility).

**Edit:**

Sorry, but above Solution won't work in a web page, as the windows object is not available there. It may only work for browser extensions.

Comment: Does this work from a web page?

Comment: The Webpage needs to implement above code, i.e. for the click event on a link. Ne normal link behavior needs to be disabled in that cases.

Comment: An extension/add-on is required to run the above code right? Because I think content pages has got no permission to execute the windows API directly?

Comment: @Rahatur You are right, I was not aware that the windows object is not accessible/available on a web page. When I posted the answer I haven't had time to test it. Now I wanted to implement it (i.e. `<a href="#" onClick="windows.create({'url': 'http://example.com'}); return false;">Test</a>`), but found that it don't work – as you said. I get the error "ReferenceError: windows is not defined".

Answer (score 3):

According to this stackoverflow answer it is impossible

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16148152/6820123

And because you don't want it because of privacy reasons, this is the reason why browsers have no such function. Browsers are made for the masses and there is a bit security and privacy way more important than a insecure function for a very special use case.

Comment: Meh.  Until browsers automatically use Tor for incognito mode, the "privacy" offered is just an illusion.  We're so far past "_don't store cookies and history_" it isn't funny.  Facebook, Amazon, Home Depot, _et al._ track you by IP address.

Comment: @RossPatterson Ironically, a tab can erase your back button history and entirely replace it.

Comment: @quanten To be fair, the answer had been provided in 2013. Given the speed of web's evolution it's only natural to keep asking "can we do x yet".